# String subscript out of range in line 1331 of xstring

Tags: c++, string, linked-list, mixing

The second while loop is throwing an exception in xstring line 1441 on the second iteration, which it should not do. This is because on the first pass:

```
Testthis->NAME[n] = 'B'
Testthis->NAME[n+1] = 'O'
Testthis->NAME = "BOD MQL"
```

are all verified from the debug `cout` statements. I am stumped on this one.

```
struct Node * ProbableMatch(struct Node * Look_in, int MaxNodes, char Findthis[64]){
system("cls");
int i=0,proba=100,CurrentHigh=100;
size_t pos1=1,n1=0,n2=0,pos2=1;
//char s[64];
struct Node * CurrentHighProb;
struct Node * Testthis;
CurrentHighProb=new(Node);
Testthis=new(Node);
Testthis=Look_in;
//for(i=0;i==MaxNodes;i++)
while(!Testthis || i!=ccounter)
{
    gotoxy(0,0);
    int n=0;
    n1=sizeof(Look_in->NAME);
    n2=sizeof(Findthis);
    string str1;
    char str2[64];
    cout<<Testthis->NAME[n]<<endl<<Testthis->NAME<<endl;
    cout<<Testthis->NAME[n+1]<<endl;

    while(Testthis->NAME[n]!='\0'){  //mannually coverts the strings since I am having hell with the inbuilt functions
        cout<<Testthis->NAME[n];
        str1[n]=Testthis->NAME[n];
        if(Testthis->NAME[n+1]=='\0'){str1[n+1]='\0';}//makes NULL terminated strings
        n++;
    }//end of while

    //strcpy_s(cstr, str1.length());
    //strcpy_s(str1,sizeof(Look_in->NAME),Look_in->NAME);
    //strcpy_s(str2,sizeof(Findthis),Findthis);
    //char * cstr1 = new char[str1.length()+1];
    cout<<str1.compare(pos1,n1,Findthis,0,n2)<<" is the value of the string compare "<<endl;
    proba=str1.compare(pos1,n1,Findthis,0,n2);//compares Findthis to the varibles read from the database from string matches

    //DEBUG STUFF
    cout<<endl<<sizeof(Look_in->NAME)<<" sizeof(Look_in->NAME)"<<Look_in->NAME<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(Findthis)<<" sizeof(Findthis)"<<Findthis<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(str1)<<" "<<str1<<" string1   string2 "<<str2<<" "<<sizeof(str2)<<endl;
    //cout<<sizeof(str1)<<" reinterpret_cast< char *>(str1)"<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    cout<<"\n Probability of "<<Look_in->NAME<<" matching "<<Findthis<<" is "<<proba<<" ."<<endl;
    //ENDOFDEBUG FOR FUNCTION
    Testthis->prob=proba;
    if(proba==0)
    {
        cout<<"proba equals zero, match found returning "<<Look_in<<endl;
        //delete[] cstr1;
        return Testthis;  // returns the pointer of the varible that best matched the search
    }
    if(proba<CurrentHigh){
        CurrentHigh=proba;
        CurrentHighProb=Testthis;
    }
    i++;
    Testthis=Testthis->next;
}
cout<<"Perfect match not found after "<<i<<" number of searches, returning this highest probable match "<<CurrentHighProb<<" "<<proba<<endl;

system("PAUSE");
//delete[] cstr1;
return CurrentHighProb;
}
```

Comment: `Testthis=new(Node); Testthis=Look_in;` Hello, memory leaks.  Consider getting a [good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) if you are interested in learning how to write correct C++ code.

Comment: Thanks but at this point I am just trying to get the function to find the correct entry, after that is done I will switch to just passing the head pointer that is deleted when the program terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string str1;
```

declares a zero-length `std::string`.

```
str1[n]=Testthis->NAME[n];
```

references the (non-existent) n'th element of `str1`.

Perhaps you mean to create a `string` with a definite length:

```
string str1(n1, ' ');
```

Or, perhaps you mean to allocate the string data during the copy:

```
str1.push_back(Testthis->NAME[n]);
```

There are other errors in your code, but this one likely produced the exception you describe.

You can avoid all of these errors simply. Replace the inner `while` loop with this:

```
str1 = Testthis->NAME;
```

Comment: Thanks. The last time I did any programming was in 98'

Comment: This `str1 = Testthis->NAME;` gives me a conversion error, cannot convert char[64] to std::string[64], should those data types be compatable?

Comment: Hmm. In the code you posted, you declared `str1` as `std::string str1;`. Did you change that to `std::string str1[64]`? In the first case, the types are compatible. In the second, they are not.